# Can a finitely generated commutative $\mathbb C$-algebra have an indecomposible representation of dimension $>1$?

Tags: representation-theory, representation-of-algebras

Can a finitely generated commutative $\mathbb C$-algebra $A$ have (a) an indecomposible or (b) irreducible representation of dimension $>1$ (over $\mathbb C$)?

Without the finite generation condition, I believe the answer is Yes. For example, I believe the group algebra $A=\mathbb C\mathbb Q$ (for the additive group $\mathbb Q$) is an irreducibible representation of itself.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thanks. So the answer to my question is No. But would you know if a finitely generated commutative C-algebra can have an irreducible representation over C, of dim >1?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Many thanks! Also may I ask why the regular representation (in the context above) must be indecomposable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Mariano's answers:
(a) The regular representation of any integral domain $A$ is indecomposible. Indeed, if $A=I\oplus J$ as an $A$-module then $I\cdot J\in I\cap J=\{0\}$.

(b) Every irreducible representation $V$ of a finitely generated commutative $\mathbb C$-algebra $A$ is $1$-dimensional. Indeed, let $\mathfrak{m}$ be a maximal ideal containing the anihilator $\mathrm{Ann}(V)$ of $V$. Then $\mathrm{Ker}(V=A/\mathrm{Ann}(V)\to A/\mathfrak{m})$  is a proper submodule of $V$ and, hence, trivial. Consequently, $V=A/\mathfrak{m}$. By [Zariski Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski%27s_lemma), the field $A/\mathfrak{m}$ must be a finite extention of $\mathbb{C}$ and, hence, $\mathbb{C}$.